# New to coding in Delphi 7: Unable to read() multiple strings

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have recently started coding in Delphi 7, mainly for school but also for personal entertainment. I have run into a problem I cannot solve. I wanted to make a console application, that asks you to input a couple of strings, such as your name and similar, so that the application may call you by your name later. However, I soon realized that having two "read();" commands for 2 different strings doesn't work for some reason, skipping the read command for the second string every time. Since I can't explain it perfectly, here is the simplest code I could think of that shows the problem:

```
program stringproblem;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

  var string1,string2:string;

begin
read(string1);
read(string2);
writeln(string1,string2);
readln;
readln;
end.
```

So the console opens, I get to write the value of string1, I input 'test', for example, but instead of letting me then input the value of string2, it skips that one, and just writes out 'test' in the console.

Why can't I input the values of two strings in an application? Why does writing the value of the first one automatically skip all others?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `Read(string1)` you should use `Readln(string1)`. And likewise for the other read, and indeed whenever you wish to consume an entire line.

From the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Read) for `Read`:

> Read reads all characters up to, but not including, the next
>   end-of-line marker or until Eof(F) becomes true; it does not skip to
>   the next line after reading.
>
> After the first Read, each subsequent Read sees the end-of-line marker
>   and returns a zero-length string.
>
> Use multiple Readln calls to read successive string values.

Comment: I have just tried doing so, changing both commands into readln, and it does work now. Thank you for your help, as stupid as my question was anyway.

Comment: The documentation links in the answer explain why `Read` won't get past the new line.

Comment: As an exercise, knowing what you know now, do you understand why your program has two `Readln` statements at the end?

Comment: I have been sitting here thinking about it and realized that I usually just used as many `Readln` statements as I needed to stop the program from closing. Were the 2 `Readln` commands needed in my program because the first `Readln` statement would return a zero-length string from the previous `Read` statement? I noticed that after correcting all `Read` statements into `Readln` statements, I would only need one `Readln` statement at the end of the program, since that one would no longer get a zero-length string from the end-of-line marker of the previous `Read` statement.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it really means a lot to someone who has barely scratched the surface of Delphi like me, and thanks for making me think about the `Readln;` situation, as I would have never thought about it without your comment. Is the registering of the end-of-line markers by subsequent `Read` statements considered a bug in Delphi, or were those `Read` statements actually supposed to register the end-of-line markers from previous lines on purpose? (as I see no function in it except for messing up variable values, and registering them as non-existent/zero-length...)

Comment: I'm not sure of the reasons behind the design, but I'm sure there are good ones. Remember that Read reads more than just strings. It can read numeric types as well. Perhaps a Pascal old-timer (not me) would be able to fill in the gaps. I'm not much of an expert on Pascal I/O to be honest with you.